# Maven versioning & repositories - How to update during build

Tags: maven, tfs

I have a project being built with maven using TFS for source control and Octopus for deployment.

At the moment, I can perform a TFS CI build, create an octopus deploy package as a zip file from the output, and use octopus to deploy to my deployment target, extract the package and install the app.

What I would like to do is increment the version of the application projects when a new build is performed (perhaps nightly).

Is the correct way to do this, to get my build server to set the new version on the project, using `mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=x.y.z` then to run `mvn deploy` to push the updated packages to the networked repository. Then to finally create my maven package from this?

I'm a bit unsure the best way to allow my build server to up issue the versions and then use those updated versions of the packages in the build.

It seems like I may have the wrong end of the stick here. Any pointers greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which Maven version do you use?

Comment: @khmarbaise I'm using 3.1.1

Comment: Why would you like to increment the version by every build? Using SNAPSHOT's or ? What not putting the version infomration of TFS into MANIFEST files to uniquely identify files on the server etc. ?

Comment: I was under the impression I'd need to know this in order to identify the specific version for deployment. I'm afraid I'm not too familiar with this process, normally we'd up issue each build so that any individual build can be deployed.

I'd be interested to know the recommended process for using maven during build, versioning and deployment. I seem to find information in isolation but not as a whole. Any pointers on guides?

Answer (score 0):

If you had already at Maven 3.2 or better Maven 3.3+ you could have done that in a more convenient way, but if you are at Maven 3.1. you need to go 
via [build-helper-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/parse-version-mojo.html) and [versions-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/versions-maven-plugin/) you can do simply via:

```
mvn build-helper:parse-version versions:set \
     -DnewVersion=\${parsedVersion.majorVersion}.\${parsedVersion.minorVersion}\${parsedVersion.nextIncrementalVersion} \
     versions:commit
```

But as far as I know the versions:commit will probably not work based on support of TFS for Maven SCM....(I never tested it with TFS). But the commit step be done by something different.

Comment: This was my worry too, the release:prepare commands don't current work for a number of issues, mainly that the path settings for maven through TFS make no sense (so it has trouble finding things I needs to run).

What I believe is happening is that the source controlled versions of the POMs are a version behind what I expect them to be.

E.g. I'm on version 0.1.0 and I ask mvn to set the version to 0.1.1 via versions:set, this appears to work, but when it then tries to deploy it seems to build the previous version 0.1.0 from source control.

Comment: I guess I'm trying to work out what the build server could (should) do, what the devs need to do locally and what I need to deploy to the local (network) maven repo (and when).

Comment: The maven-release-plugin does not work with TFS, cause I have tested that....If you think they behind for whatever reason there is something wrong. You need to checkout the pom file to be able to change them via versions:set in TFS....

Comment: Yeah, this kind of confirms what I though (that the devs will have to run versions:set locally then check in the new versions).

The build server could then do the deploy to local (networked) repo, and create the installer packages.

Comment: Why not creating a script which will do the checkin and run that on the build server...more convenient...

Comment: Our normal workflow is that the build server CI build is triggered by the checkin from the devs from their local machines.

When you say a script to do the check in, do you mean run a manual command line check in, from the build server? I'm not sure how that would work or how that would be more convenient. 

Apologies if I'm way off the mark here. Just trying to get a grasp on the concepts and workflows within Maven coming from a C#/TFS background.

Comment: How often do the Dev's need to change the version? This can be achieved by a script which runs on the build server and simply be triggered by a dev...